# Generic Data Set

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I need to make a general class for transform Tuple data, to Data Set. Is possible to call "unknown data method's" with different return type. For example `<Tuple<List<string,int>>, <Tuple<List<int,int>>` and put it in like generic type?

I have a generic Class

```
static class Helper<T>
{
    public static DataSet Transform(T data)
    {
        ...transform logic
        return new DataSet();
    }
}
```

And another class, which call different methods, which return different types.

For example, I call a method which returns this type:
`Tuple<List<Tuple<long, string, string>>, List<Tuple<long, string, string>>>` and I try to call generic class method Transform and insert specific date type, which I get from method result by `GetType()`. But I have a problem with it.

For Example - this work, I set string like generic type and string content.

```
Helper<string>.Transform("test");
```

But if I want to use "unknown" type, I don't know, how I put it like date type.

```
var data = Data.GetData();
var type = data.GetType();
//this doesn't work
Helper<type>.Transform(data);
```

I hope so my question is clear.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the past I have used a non generic class and a method with a type parameter  e.g.
    ```public static DataSet Transform(Type type, Object data)```  Also look up ```Activator.CreateInstance``` if you need to create an instance of a partiicular type.

Comment: Oh thanks, Type and Object like input works fine, i want to try some generic, but if it doesn't work, i will use it.